# Do Dev Dependencies go into a produced work?

Tags: derivative-works, open-data

I am working on a project that has a dependency on [eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y) which depends on [language-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/language-tags) which depends on [language-subtag-registry](https://github.com/mattcg/language-subtag-registry) which holds data under [Open Data Commons Attribution License (ODC-By) v1.0](https://opendatacommons.org/licenses/by/1-0/).
The data in question is basically a mapping of language names to their abbreviation.

Thus Black Duck says:

> You are required to include a notice in product documentation with certain requirements as specified by the license

Now I'm trying to find out if this applies to my situation.

The term 'notice' appears twice in the License:

> 4.3 [...] if you Publicly Use a Produced Work, You must [...]

> "Produced Work" - a work (such as an image, audiovisual material, text, or
> sounds) resulting from using the whole or a Substantial part of the Contents (via
> a search or other query) from this Database, a Derivative Database, or this
> Database as part of a Collective Database.

So none of the relevant data is flowing into the final project but it is used to produce the resulting work. Or is it? It is just part of my workflow after all but not required for the build...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this plugin for ESLint is only used in your build process, then the warning from Black Duck is a false-positive.

With linters like ESLint it is safe to say that removing them from your build system will have no effect on the created output. That is a very strong indication that no copyrightable portions of those tools end up in the final product and therefor that the product ,can also not be affected by the license of the tool.